# How to install Colour Scale Bar for One-Band Rasters

Tags: qgis, scale, color

I am new to QGIS. I want to generate a Colormap of a picture. I searched and found one plugin-Colour Scale Bar for One-Band Rasters-can do this. But I didn't find it the the plugins. Is anyone know why?

Comment: Visit [BC Consulting](http://www.bc-consult.com/free/bccscbar.html) website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their plugin is not available in the official repositorium. but you can add them like in the image below[image]

installing and following should look like this[image]